# Cannot Send Packets From Android UDP Connection through Crossover Cable

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp

I am trying to send/receive UDP packets on my Android tablet. I have a Java program set up on my Windows laptop using the same UDP reader/writer classes as on my tablet (the Android reader and the computer writer are using the same port, and vice versa), and I am using a crossover cable and a USB-ethernet adapter to connect the two.

I am consistently able to receive packets on the tablet from the computer. However, sending packets from the tablet to the computer often gives me an `java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)` error, even when I can receive packets over the same network.

If I turn on the tablet's wireless I no longer get the error, but I do not get the packets over the ethernet connection.

I was able to get the system to work when I plugged it into a network with a switch, so I am wondering if there is some underlying networking setting that my computer is missing.

Alternately: is there a way to tell it to try sending out UDP packets, regardless of whether it thinks it's connected?

For these classes, the `serverIP` is the address of the computer that the tablet is attempting to communicate with. `serverPort` on each corresponds with what the other side is looking for.

UDP Writer class:

```
public void sendMessage(final SentMessage message) {
try {
    try (DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open()) {
        try (DatagramSocket socket = channel.socket()) {
            socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(this.serverPort));
            byte[] byteArray = message.buildByteArray(false);
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(byteArray, byteArray.length, this.serverIP, this.serverPort);
            socket.send(sendPacket);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    log.log(Level.SEVERE,  e.getMessage(), e);
    e.printStackTrace();

} }
```

UDP Reader class:

```
protected void runServer() {

try {
    try (DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open()) {
        try (DatagramSocket socket = channel.socket()) {
            socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(this.serverPort));                
            int messageSize = 48;
            while (this.mRun) {
                //Read in packet
                final byte[] messageBytes = new byte[messageSize];
                DatagramPacket receivedMessage = new DatagramPacket(messageBytes, messageSize, this.serverIP, this.serverPort);
                socket.receive(receivedMessage);

                //Convert to known message type
                //...
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.log(Level.SEVERE,  e.getMessage(), e);
    e.printStackTrace();

} }
```

Comment: Probably, something is wrong with your USB-ETH adapter. Try to test ping from Windows and Android device to check the connection stability. For Android, you can try [PingMeter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=local.pivot.pingmeter&hl=en)

Comment: It appears to be a common problem with the Android 5.x+ update on the Samsung Galaxy Tab. I am about to try this:
http://androidmobilezy.blogspot.com/2015/10/enabling-ethernet-over-usb-otg.html